# How to replace a video in an existing post on Instagram?

Tags: instagram

The video quality after upload/Instagram compression looks terrible and I'd like to replace/improve the video but maintain the post (and likes/comments/etc.)

Is it possible to replace the video in an existing Instagram post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only alter the caption of the video but not the actual video itself.
I see you have posted one more question related to the information regarding Instagram video, check out my answer [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101847/how-to-upload-a-high-quality-video-to-instagram/101860#101860)

Comment: thank you(+1). that's what I was afraid of: having to do a new post.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, do mark the answer as correct