# How to upload a high quality video to Instagram?

Tags: instagram

I have an 1080p HD video edited on a computer that I'd like to upload to Instagram. The issue is that on my first attempt, even though I selected landscape format instead of the square format, Instagram re-compressed the video and it looks terrible.

How can I avoid compression when uploading a 1080p video to Instagram?

(So far I found [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Instagram/comments/475ukn/how_to_post_hd_video_to_instagram_and_avoid/) about the issue - I couldn't find any recommended video settings (dimensions/frame rate/bit rate/etc.) on Instagram help.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can upload within the below limits:

```
Size: Maximum width: 1080 pixels (any height)
Frame Rate: 29.96 frames per second
Codec: H.264 codec / MP4
Bit-rate: 3,500 kbps video bitrate
Audio: AAC audio codec at 44.1 kHz mono
Length: 60 seconds
Filesize: 15MB
```

Hope it helps

Comment: awesome! thank you for this(+1). do you mind sharing a reference to where this information is from ?

Comment: I found this on a number of places, you can check here http://www.brorsoft.com/tutorial/upload-videos-to-instagram.html